# For measurable $f$ and continuous $g$ on $\mathbb{R}$, $f \circ g$ is measurable?

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Here measurability is in the context of Lebesgue measure.

So if we suppose $f$ defined on $\mathbb{R}$ is measurable and $g$ on $\mathbb{R}$ continuous then $f \circ g$ is necessarily measurable?

I vote on no. But it's quite hard to find a counterexample.

Please some help.

Comment: See Example [8.38](http://books.google.com/books?id=cDAMh5n4lkkC&pg=PA109&source=gbs_toc_r&cad=4#v=onepage&q&f=false) in Gelbaum and Olmsted's *Counterexamples in Analysis*.

Comment: Many Thanks!!1 By chance I happen to own this book.

Answer (score 0):

For those who don't have a book, here is an example. Let $g$ be a homeomorphism squeezing a fat Cantor set $F$ into the standard $1/3$-Cantor set $C$, as [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/736146/127096). Let $E$ be a non-measurable subset of $F$. The function $f = \chi_E\circ g^{-1}$ vanishes outside of $C$ and therefore is measurable. But $f\circ g = \chi_E$ is not.